# Get count of each value from each column in the table

Tags: sql, clickhouse

As the title says, I have a table from which I need to count each row from each column.
I have an SQL query, which selects needed rows based on `WHERE` and `BETWEEN` keywords:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT pg, count(*) FROM analytics WHERE pid='STEzHcB1rALV' AND created BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-28' GROUP BY pg
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dv, count(*) FROM analytics WHERE pid='STEzHcB1rALV' AND created BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-28' GROUP BY dv
  UNION ALL
  SELECT br, count(*) FROM analytics WHERE pid='STEzHcB1rALV' AND created BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-28' GROUP BY br
  UNION ALL
  SELECT os, count(*) FROM analytics WHERE pid='STEzHcB1rALV' AND created BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-28' GROUP BY os
  UNION ALL
  SELECT lc, count(*) FROM analytics WHERE pid='STEzHcB1rALV' AND created BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-28' GROUP BY lc 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ref, count(*) FROM analytics WHERE pid='STEzHcB1rALV' AND created BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-28' GROUP BY ref 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT so, count(*) FROM analytics WHERE pid='STEzHcB1rALV' AND created BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-28' GROUP BY so
  UNION ALL
  SELECT me, count(*) FROM analytics WHERE pid='STEzHcB1rALV' AND created BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-28' GROUP BY me 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ca, count(*) FROM analytics WHERE pid='STEzHcB1rALV' AND created BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-28' GROUP BY ca
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cc, count(*) FROM analytics WHERE pid='STEzHcB1rALV' AND created BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-28' GROUP BY cc
);
```

The problem is that for each column it seems to select partition of table (based on `WHERE` and `BETWEEN`) each time, which looks a bit unoptimised.

I've tried to optimise it by creating the next query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT pg,dv,br,os,lc,ref,so,me,ca,cc FROM analytics WHERE pid='STEzHcB1rALV' AND created BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-28' INTO table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY pg
  UNION ALL
  SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY dv
  UNION ALL
  SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY br
  UNION ALL
  SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY os
  UNION ALL
  SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY lc 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY ref 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY so
  UNION ALL
  SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY me 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY ca
  UNION ALL
  SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY cc
);
```

but it returns an error: `Code: 60. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Table analytics.table doesn't exist. (UNKNOWN_TABLE)`.

The current database I use is Clickhouse.

Is there a way how I can optimise this query?
Why does the DBMS returns this `table doesn't exist` error?

Comment: Table reserve name in sql change table into tables and create table with tables name

Answer (score 1):

You're using `count()` with group by and this looks like you want to count unique values from each of the columns.
Instead can you `uniq` (or `uniqExact` for the strict precision)

```sql
SELECT 
    uniq(pg),
    uniq(dv),
    uniq(br),
    uniq(os),
    uniq(lc),
    uniq(ref),
    uniq(so),
    uniq(me),
    uniq(ca),
    uniq(cc),
FROM analytics
WHERE pid='STEzHcB1rALV' AND created BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-28'
```

This will give results in one row.

Comment: The problem is that I need to count not how many unique rows are there in the table, but how many times each row (value) appears in the specified column..

Comment: My request will count number of unique values in every specified column

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [sumMap](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/summap/) aggregated function:

```sql
SELECT
    pid,
    v1_result,
    v2_result
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        pid,
        sumMap([v1], [1]) AS _value1_to_count,
        arrayMap((value, count) -> (value, count), _value1_to_count.1, _value1_to_count.2) AS v1_result,
        sumMap([v2], [1]) AS _value2_to_count,
        arrayMap((value, count) -> (value, count), _value2_to_count.1, _value2_to_count.2) AS v2_result
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            number % 5 AS pid,
            number % 2 AS v1,
            number % 3 AS v2
        FROM numbers(256)
    )
    WHERE pid = 4
    GROUP BY pid
)

/*

(0,26) means that value '0' appeared 26 times in the column 'v1_result'.

┌─pid─┬─v1_result───────┬─v2_result──────────────┐
│   4 │ [(0,26),(1,25)] │ [(0,17),(1,17),(2,17)] │
└─────┴─────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
*/
```

---

Consider using [uniqExact](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/uniqexact/) aggregated function:

```sql
SELECT
    pid,
    uniqExact(v1),
    uniqExact(v2)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        number % 5 AS pid,
        number % 2 AS v1,
        number % 3 AS v2
    FROM numbers(256)
)
WHERE pid = 4
GROUP BY pid

/*
┌─pid─┬─uniqExact(v1)─┬─uniqExact(v2)─┐
│   4 │             2 │             3 │
└─────┴───────────────┴───────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to count not how many unique rows are there in the table, but how many times each row (value) appears in the specified column..

Comment: @Andrew ok - I see, look at the updated answer.